# Powershell 6 missing cmdlets

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-core, powershell-6.0

Why are cmdlets like `Test-NetConnection` no longer available? It appears the entire `NetTCPIP` module is not in v6. Is there a list of depreciated cmdlets in Powershell Core?

`Get-Module -n Microsoft.PowerShell.Management | select -exp ExportedCommands` in v6 is about half that in v5.

Comment: I'm not sure about the specific cmdlet that you are asking about but yes, V6 has many fewer cmdlets than v5 and will probably continue to have fewer for quite some time. Unless you are explicitly writing *nix or cross platform compatible scripts you should probably be using v5.

Comment: PowerShell 6 is the multi-platform version of PowerShell which means it only supports those cmdlets that were ported.  Windows-specific cmdlets were not ported, as they wouldn't be usable, under those other platforms.

Comment: You might get more information asking this question on http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Not likely. The answer is that V6 has fewer cmdlets than windows specific versions. Period.

Comment: @Ramhound Note that at least some of the `NetTCPIP` cmdlets _are not_ inherently Windows specific.  Unless they touch very low level OS interfaces, they can at least theoretically be ported.  `Test-NetConnection` should actually be pretty easy, it's just a port of the old BSD `ping` command with typical MS 'different just to be different' changes.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - The comment was very generalized.  [In this case, the `NetTCPIP` PowerShell module only exist within the Windows and has not been ported to PowerShell 6.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/?view=win10-ps)

Comment: I will also point out that since Powershell V6 is open source, if it is missing something that you feel it should have, just head on over to github and start coding.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell 6 is cross-platform, so cmdlets that relied on native functions had to be rewritten or removed. Apparently Microsoft never got around to reimplementing `Test-NetConnection` for other platforms. Cmdlets that manage Windows-only systems (e.g. Storage Spaces) all had to be removed. To produce a list of all the missing cmdlets, you can use PowerShell!

First run this in PowerShell 5:

```
Get-Command | select Name, Source | Export-Csv .\cmds5.csv
```

Then run it again in PowerShell 6 with a different output file:

```
Get-Command | select Name, Source | Export-Csv .\cmds6.csv
```

We can then analyze the files for differences using either PowerShell version:

```
$cmd5 = Import-Csv .\cmds5.csv
$cmd6 = Import-Csv .\cmds6.csv
$gone = $cmd5 | ? { $n = $_.Name; ($cmd6 | ? { $_.Name -eq $n }) -eq $null }
$new = $cmd6 | ? { $n = $_.Name; ($cmd5 | ? { $_.Name -eq $n }) -eq $null }
```

I tested this in a Windows 10 1703 x86 VM that should have pretty fresh PowerShell environments. I used [v6.0.2](https://github.com/powershell/powershell/releases/tag/v6.0.2) for PowerShell 6, the most recent stable version. Of the 1493 commands in PowerShell 5, **1139** were removed in PowerShell 6. I put them all in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Fleex255/f5e978c6b00d42d9698134854b566ea0). Of the 425 commands in PowerShell 6, 71 are new, all but three of which have to do with desired state configuration. Those last three are `Get-Uptime`, `Remove-Alias`, and `Remove-Service`. You can see all new commands in [this other gist](https://gist.github.com/Fleex255/e73429745dd678522b405dc3c6f8deb4).

Comment: Interesting that those last three are missing from powershell 5.1 too...

Comment: Is there a way to get the missing cmdlets so I can use them in Powershell 6? I use `Start-BitsTransfer` a lot, for example.

Comment: @Ray [This module](https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility) claims to enable the use of Windows-specific modules. However, it seems to require WinRM being on.